# Calling the destructor of derived class

Tags: c++

Why was destructor of Derived class called in this code?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
   Base() { std::cout << "Base::Base() \n"; }
   ~Base() { std::cout << "Base::~Base() \n"; } 
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   Derived() { std::cout << "Derived::Derived() \n"; }
   ~Derived() { std::cout << "Derived::~Derived() \n"; } 
};

Derived foo() { return Derived(); }

int main()
{
   const Derived& instance = foo();
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Because a `Derived` object was destroyed. The implication in your question is that you think the destructor wouldn't be called. Why is this?

Comment: What did you expect? You can not return a local object because it will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: It looks like the entire `Base` class is nothing but a red herring. It has nothing to do with the question at all?!

Comment: There isn't virtual keyword for destructor in Base class

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Why do you think that is relevant? You never `delete` a `Derived` object through a pointer to `Base`.

Comment: It's UB only when using new and delete for classes which hasn't virtual destructor?

Comment: See here for virtual destructor information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681790/parent-class-has-a-virtual-function-is-it-necessary-to-have-a-virtual-destructo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why was destructor of Derived class called in this code?

Because the `Derived` instance created in `foo()` is going out of scope at the end of main program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Base::Base() \n";
    }
    ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Base::~Base() \n";
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    int i;
    Derived() {
        i = 10;
        std::cout << "Derived::Derived() \n";
    }
    ~Derived() {
        i = 0;
        std::cout << "Derived::~Derived() \n";
    }
    int get() {
        return i;
    }
};

Derived foo() {
    return Derived();
}

int main() {
    const Derived& instance = foo();
    cout << instance.i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
10
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

Comment: `instance` isn't an object. It's a reference. References going out of scope don't usually cause destructors to be called. I think you need to expand your explanation.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, I spoke too soon without checking it's a reference and thought OP got confused with virtual function behavior. Corrected my explanation. Thanks for correcting!

Comment: In this case, the reference is initialized with a temporary (whose lifetime is extended to match that of the reference), so although `instance` isn't an object, it has an object associated with it.

Answer (score 3):

To make it more interesting, consider a modified `main`:

```
const Base& instance = foo();
```

That code creates a temporary (the object returned by `foo`) of type `Derived` and extends the lifetime of the object by binding it to a constant reference of type `Base`. The lifetime of the temporary will be extended until the reference goes out of scope at which point the object will get destroyed. The code is roughly translated to:

```
Derived __tmp = foo();
const Base& instance = __tmp;
```

At the end of the block holding the reference `instance`, the `__tmp` variable also goes out of scope and gets deleted. Note that even with no virtual destructor, the appropriate destructor is called, as `__tmp` is of type `Derived` (the type returned by the function).